# Finding multiple formats of names and addresses using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have several text files from which I am trying to capture some names and addresses using regex.

In all of the files the Name lines, street line, and city lines are always grouped together without any blank lines between.  I think I regex can be used to make the capture most reliable but I am getting stuck fine tuning my regex ( see mine further down )

Sometimes there is a Name (without comma separator) followed by address:

XMG GROUP LLC 
2323 FILMORE APT 200 
ST LOUIS.  MO. 63101

555-666-7777

Sometimes Name is repeated and arranged Family, Given Middle:

JOHN E PARKER
PARKER, JOHN E
150 ORANGE RIVER DR APT#T
WENTZVILLE MO 63002

Sometimes only the Family, Given Middle format is present:

ORTEGA, VALERY
2264 GLENWOOD EAST DR
MARYVILLE HEIGHTS, MO. 63533

555-222-1111

There are about 5 possibilities for the Name lines:

1)
JOHN E PARKER
PARKER, JOHN E

2)
PARKER, JOHN E

3)
JOHN E PARKER

4)
JOHN E PARKER
PARKER, JOHN

5)
PARKER, JOHN

**This is what I have tried so far:**

`(?:^\s{0,4}(?<Name>[^\r\n,-]{2,64}))?\r\n(?:^\s{0,4}\b(?<Family>\w{2,64}),\s{0,4}(?<Given>\w{2,64})(?:\s{1,4})?(?<Middle>[a-zA-Z]{1,16})?\r\n)(?<Steet>[^\r\n]{2,64})`

I am doing this in C# and trying it with `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`

Answer (score 1):

```cs
@"(?<Address>^\d[^\n]*\n[^\n]+\d$)|(?:^(?<Family>[a-z]{2,64}), (?<Name>[a-z]{2,64})(?: (?<Middle>[a-z]{1,16}))?)|(?:^(?<Name>[a-z]{2,64}) (?:(?<Middle>[a-z]{1,16}) )?(?<Family>[a-z]{2,64}))$";
```

**Note:** this expects you to use [`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regexoptions-ignorecase).

---

In pseudo regex this pattern matches:

```
<Address line 1>
<Address line 2>
```

or

```
<Family>, <Name> <Middle>
```

or

```
<Name> <Middle> <Family>
```

And `<Middle>` is always optional.

Try it https://regex101.com/r/HxEIWy/1

Comment: Thanks for this. It definitely helps out with the names, it doesn't capture the addresses though

Comment: @TendekaiMuchenje oops, I missed that somehow. I've updated my answer to capture the address too.